# Add new field at the end of each line based on value of existing field (sed or awk)

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a set of CSV files which I wish to add a field at the end of each line.

The first field is an ID, some ten-digit number:

```
id,2nd_field,...,last_field
1234567890,Smith,...,Arkansas
1234567891,Jones,...,California
1234567892,White,...,
```

I want to add another field at the end where the value is based on modulo 3 (id % 3) of the ID:

```
id,2nd_field,...,last_field,added_field
1234567890,Smith,...,Arkansas,x
1234567891,Jones,...,California,y
1234567892,White,...,,z
```

Please take into account the fact that the *last_field* could be null or blank.

How to do this using sed or awk? I'm a newbie on using these tools, kindly provide as well some explanation to your script. Thanks.

Comment: wat do u have so far? annoying repeated question

Comment: @Cyrus already saw the link. This is what it should look like (maybe) `sed 's/$/,/' input.csv > output.csv`, but don't know how to refer to the first field and operate a modulo.

Comment: @anubhava Let's just say, `$1 % 3 == 0` we get x, `$1 % 3 == 1` we get y, `$1 % 3 == 2` we get z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print $0, "added_field"; next}
     ($1%3)==0{p="x"} ($1%3)==1{p="y"} ($1%3)==2{p="z"} {print $0, p}' file
```

**Output:**

```
id,2nd_field,...,last_field,added_field
1234567890,Smith,...,Arkansas,x
1234567891,Jones,...,California,y
1234567892,White,...,,z
```

Comment: What's appended is the result of the modulo operation. I may need to use another sed for it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Module result is already there in the result, what output do you expect?

Comment: Okay got it. Here's what worked for me. `awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { if ($1 % 3 == 0) print $0",x"; else if ($1 % 3 == 1) print $0",y"; else print $0",z" }' file`. Sorry, it should not have the header row. Thanks anyway for giving me an idea.

Comment: Didn't realize you needed literal `x,y,z` in the output. I've modified the answer slightly from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; split("y,z,x",map) }
{ print $0, (NR>1 ? map[($1-1)%3+1] : "added_field") }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
id,2nd_field,...,last_field,added_field
1234567890,Smith,...,Arkansas,x
1234567891,Jones,...,California,y
1234567892,White,...,,z
```

The above just uses `split()` to create a mapping of:

```
map[1] = y
map[2] = z
map[3] = x
```

and then accesses it when needed via the common `(VALUE-1)%N+1` syntax that maps mod `N` results for values `1,2,..,N-1,N` to `1,2,..,N-1,N` instead of `1,2,..,N-1,0`:

```
map[($1-1)%3+1]
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<=6;i++) print i, i%3, (i-1)%3+1 }'
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 0 3
4 1 1
5 2 2
6 0 3
```